# Issue with MYSQL connection in Wordpress - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I am having an issue with my Database lookup code: [Website Here](http://mainstaycomputing.com/client/prospects/list-brokers-resources/sic-code-search/?sic=med)

It is very odd because I am on a webhost (Godaddy) and I have confirmed nothing is wrong on their end.

It was working perfectly before but then I got on to some other projects and I came back to this error. {Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)}
 which is caused when the search form successfully tries to query the database.

Any help would be really appreciated

```
  Paste your text here<?php

get_header();

?>



<div id="main-content" style = 'position: relative'>

    <div class = 'wrapper'> 

    <h1 class="entry-title main_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


    <div class = 'sic-text'>
        <p> SIC codes are assigned by the Government and are standard at the 4 digit level.
            The 8 digit codes may be customized by each individual list owner. Because we represent all list
            sources, there may be variance in what the 8 digit codes represent. For greatest accuracy,
            when speaking with one of our List Brokers please supply the sic code # along with a description so
            we can provide as exact a match as possible.To use this search, simply type the Industry you’re
            looking for into the Search By Keyword field. For instance, entering “Dentists” will cause all
            businesses related to dentists listed. <! — If you know the SIC code and want to know the industry
            name, enter the 8 digit code into the Search By Code field. –> </p>

    </div>




    <form action="" method="GET" class = 'sic-search'> 



    <input class = 'sic-search-text' type="text" name="sic" placeholder="Search for an industry, eg 'Agriculture'"/>


    <input type="submit" value="Search" class = 'sic-search-button'/>
    </form>


<?php 
echo $error;
$sic = $_GET['sic'];

$servername='confidential';
$username='confidential';
$password='confidential';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

 $min_length = 2;
    // you can set minimum length of the sic if you want

    if(strlen($sic) >= $min_length && $sic != ''){ // if sic length is more or equal minimum length then

        $sic = htmlspecialchars($sic); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $sic = mysql_real_escape_string($sic);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection


         $sql =  SELECT * FROM siccodes WHERE (`description` LIKE '%".$sic."%') OR (`two-digit-sic` LIKE '%".$sic."%') OR (`description-2` LIKE '%".$sic."%') OR (`four-digit-sic` LIKE '%".$sic."%') OR (`description-3` LIKE '%".$sic."%') OR (`six-digit-sic` LIKE '%".$sic."%');

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

echo "<p style = 'text-align:center; margin-bottom: 10px;' id = 'rowCount'> </p>";

echo "<div class = 'print-container'>";
echo "<button class = 'print-button' onclick='window.print()'> Print  </button>"; 
echo "</div>";


echo "<div style = 'overflow-x: auto;'>
<table class = 'sic-code-table'>
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Two Digit SIC</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Four Digit SIC</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Six Digit SIC</th>
</tr>";



    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $results['description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['two-digit-sic'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['description-2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['four-digit-sic'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['description-3'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['six-digit-sic'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

        } else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "<p style = 'text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px; color: red;'>No results match '$sic' Please try another search term.</p>";
        }

    }else {
        if ($sic != '') {
        echo "<p style = 'text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px; color: red;'> Please search again, '$sic' is to short.</p>";
        }

    } // end of checking mimimum string number
?>

<?php if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 100) : ?>
<form action="" method="GET" class = 'sic-search'>



    <input class = 'sic-search-text' type="text" name="sic" placeholder="Search for an industry, eg 'Agriculture'"/>


    <input type="submit" value="Search" class = 'sic-search-button'/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>




    </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->


</script>
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?> :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, it can't work for you have not initiated any DB connection.
Second thing is, WP got own class to work with DBs, called wpdb. Please use it to interact with a WP database. Information on this class, its methods and etc can be found in the [documenation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) or [old documenation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

You could do something like

```
global $wpdb;
// do your escaping stuff
$results = $wpdb->get_results('your query', ARRAY_A);
if(count($results) > 0)
{
    foreach($results as $item)
    {
        //output items here as $item['column_name'];
    }
}
```

Please note, this is just a very basic example. Read documentation provided above to gain better understanding of `wpdb` class, best practices and so on.

Comment: I am just wondering as to why it would have worked before... I had that thought but It just did not make much sense, Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @chrislawson It could work before if `mysql_connect` was used before to open a connection. In your current code it doesn't happen so there is no connection for `mysql_query` to use. With wpdb, you don't have to worry about initiating a connection since it's done during initialization of WP. I've added basic example into my answer.

Comment: Thank you Igor! I am just going to do it with a regular connection as I am pressed for time but I will look into that in the future.  I have posted the updated version.  I am having an issue with the Query now on line 66.  Could you help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Check to see that your socket is properly listed in my.cnf

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

#### Check to see if mysql is running

```
service mysql status
```

#### or

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

***Don't forget permission error may cause this, change mysql's directory permission as follows:***

```
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

#### Restart mysql-server

```
service mysql restart
```

#### NJOY

Comment: It is not local. That would only apply to that right?

Comment: @chrislawson if the database is not local, you may not have access to tweak the configuration, however you may want to ensure that you can connect directly to the database server either remotely or locally, if you cannot connect, your apps will not be able to connect.  Use `mysql -u username -h remote-ip-of-db-server -p` if you can login then you are good to go.